# Olympiad Matrix Type of question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contest-math

Suppose $A$ is a $10\times 10$ matrix with integer entries,  with the following property: given any five rows and five columns, the sum of the entries of the $5\times 5$ matrix formed by these rows and columns is even. Prove that all of the entries of $A$ are even.

I'm stumped in finding an eloquent and precise solution to this problem.

Comment: Out of interest, where is the problem from?

Comment: It's Olympiad style questions that we're given as part of revision for my final exam.

Answer (score 3):

Since all we care about is whether the entries are even or odd, we may as well work over $\mathbb{F}_2$ and ask whether the entries are $1$ or $0$. The $5\times 5$ sum condition may be restated as the following property: $x^T A y = 0$ for any vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{F}_2^{10}$ which have $5$ zeroes and $5$ ones in their entries.

We can extend this to a larger class of vectors as follows: if $x^T A y_1 = 0$ and $x^T A y_2 = 0$, then $x^T A (y_1+y_2) = 0$. We can write the vector $e_1 = (1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ as the sum of the vectors $y_1 = (1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)$, $y_2 = (1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)$, and $y_3 = (1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)$, and deduce that $x^T A e_1 = x^T A (y_1 + y_2 + y_3) = 0$ for any $x$ with $5$ zeroes and $5$ ones.

There's nothing special about $e_1$; we can do this for any $e_j$. Similarly, we can apply this idea to the row vectors on the left side of $A$: if $x_1^T A e_j = 0$ and $x_2^T A e_j = 0$, then $(x_1 +x_2)^T A e_j = 0$, so we get $e_i^T A e_j = 0$ for any $i$ and $j$.

But this just says that $A_{ij} = 0$ for any $i$ and $j$. Going back from $\mathbb{F}_2$ to the integers, this says that for any $i$ and $j$, $A_{ij}$ is even, as desired.